# How to scroll storyboard in XCode while Ctrl key pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'am developing application on Macbook Pro with a lot of view controllers in Storyboard.
Screen resolution is not very big, and sometimes I need to scroll editor, while dragging segues (with Ctrl key pressed).

With Apple mouse it is impossible.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I do this when I'm developing on a small Macbook is to use the window on the left where it shows your view hierarchy.  That way you don't have to use the actual storyboard, and you can usually control drag between any of the components...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this can be very annoying.  While you are dragging your segue, bring your cursor to the edge of the storyboard in the direction you would like to scroll. ( A little bit closer to the edge than in my attached image)  Pause with your cursor there, and the screen will begin to scroll in that direction.

[image]

Comment: Be sure to keep the cursor away from touching any other views along the way or it will stop scrolling though! It seems Apple takes some kind of sadistic pleasure out of making this as hard as humanly possible.